# Check for particular Child ViewModel in WPF panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to WPF, and am currently working on a project to test my knowledge.

I have a panel on which I would like to change different views on, but the view should be changed only if it is not the current child element of the panel.. So I wrote code that looks like this

```
 public void OnAddNewQuestionBank(object paramter)
 {
        var childIsCurrent = _mainWindow.ContentBox.Children.OfType<AddQuestionsPane>().Equals(typeof(AddQuestionsPane));

        if(!childIsCurrent)
        {
            //Display the panel
            _mainWindow.ContentBox.Children.Add(new AddQuestionsPane());
        }            
 }
```

But I realised that the `childIsCurrent` always returns false... How do I solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OfType<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` object. It does not equal a `Type`, which is why that always returns false. Instead, you could try and see if there are any items in the `IEnumerable<T>`. For example:

```
var childIsCurrent = _mainWindow.ContentBox.Children.OfType<AddQuestionsPane>().Any();
```

Comment: Ohh, I get it... Thanks'